# In Xcode and IOS projects I can't use constants. Got linker build errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, constants, linker-errors

I started a new iOS project in Xcode. Added two files: "constants.h" and "constants.m" with this content I saw here in other articles:

Constants.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/// Holds the username for connection to the API
extern NSString * const PSUsername_preferences;

/// Holds the password for connection to the API
extern NSString *const PSPassword_preferences; 

///Holds the (hopefully) secure server URL. (Defaults to https://API.SomewhatURL.de)
extern NSString *const PSServername_preferences;
```

And the constants.m:

```
#import "Constants.h" 

NSString *const PSUsername_preference = @"username_preferences";
NSString *const PSPassword_preference = @"password_preferences";
NSString *const PSServer_preference = @"servername_preferences";
```

I am sure, the .m file is assigned to build for my ios-target. 
I am also sure, the file is added under Build Configurations- Compile Sources.

Next I added the "Constats.h" to my pch - file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

and I can assign one of these in let say `AddDelegate`:

```
 NSString * value = PSUsername_preferences;
```

Nice. 
But: If I try to build this, I get a strange linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>    "_PSUsername_preferences", referenced from:
>        -[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This happens with a new created project just for this case. My build settings seem OK and I already checked 'Architectures' path under Build-Settings. All of they show 'ArmV7' but not i386, so whats going on?

I tested it on `Xcode 4.6.3` as well as under `Xcode 5`.

Comment: i386 is for the simulator.

Comment: Good point! If I connect my device and start build/run on that I get a _Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_PSUsername_preferences", referenced from:_ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your constant names letter by letter. Or add some whitespace for easier readability.

```
extern NSString * const PSUsername_preferences;
       NSString * const PSUsername_preference
```

You see the difference? Add the letter `s` at the end of your definitions.

Comment: Argg!  Didn't see the forest for the trees.. Thats it! Thank you!

Comment: Interesting to notice that Xcode autocomplete suggest the header declaration. Only the build shows me this strange behavior. I am comming from the VB.NET corner so this kind of build errors are still a bit strange to me. Today I have learned another important lesson..